# Shiny Dashboard- How to add text for Sidebar items

Tags: r, shiny

I was trying to add website information on my shiny dashboard and for the "About" section (See image) I want few lines to be displayed on the dashboard body when clicked on that tab. how could i possibly achieve it? I could successfully add href for the "contact" section. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I do not understand your question properly, but what about:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

header <- dashboardHeader()

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    id = "tabs",
    menuItem("About", icon = icon("info"), tabName = "about"),
    menuItem("Contact", icon = icon("phone"), tabName = "contact")
    )
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem("about",
            h1("About")),
    tabItem("contact",
            h1("Contact"))
  )
)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body),
  server = function(input, output) { }
)
```

When you click on `About` you get a new tab in the `dashboardBody` where you can display whatever you want.

---

**Update**

Based on your clarification you can use `shinyjs` to `hide`/`show` the relevant part:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)

header <- dashboardHeader()

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    id = "tabs",
    menuItem("About", icon = icon("info"), tabName = "about"),
    menuItem("Contact", icon = icon("phone"), tabName = "contact")
  )
)
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  useShinyjs(),
  fluidPage(
    fluidRow(id = "mainContent",
      column(12, h1("Main Content"))
    ),
    hidden(fluidRow(id = "contact", h1("Contact Info")))
  )
)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body),
  server = function(input, output) {
    observe({
      if (input$tabs == "contact") {
        hideElement("mainContent")
        showElement("contact")
      } else {
        hideElement("contact")
        showElement("mainContent")
      }
    })
  }
)
```

When you now click on `Contact` the main part is hidden and the contact is shown. I have, however, the feeling that is a bit mis-using the idea of `shinydashboard`.

Comment: Thank you for your kind patience thothal, it worked! However, based on your opinion of misusing dashboard, I searched for alternatives. I guess I should instead be using Navbar, right? Coz my idea is just to display a data table and add  About and contact section on the webpage.

Comment: I think the idea of `shinydashboard` is that you organize your content on tabs. For each `menuItem` you define one tab with different content on it. This boils down to my first proposal.So I would define 3 `menuItems`: one for the data table and the other 2. Then you do not need the JS trick.

Comment: Hmm okay, But what would your view be on Navbar? I am fairly new to shiny apps and just wanted to know what would be the best bet for my kind of requirement.

Comment: Navbar is the same concept. I think you can go with either. Define a main tab with your data table (it also gets  a corresponding menu entry) and the links in your sidebar or your navbar allow you to switch from contact to main tab easily.

Answer (score 0):

@thothal, it did not allow me to add as a comment coz of the length, hence posting my comment(below) as an answer.

I am sorry if I was unclear. However, your answer helped me partially. I have incorporated `tabItems` part in my `dashboardBody` section, as shown below:

```
dashboardBody(
    fluidPage(
       fluidRow(
          column(12, div(dataTableOutput("dataTable")))
       )
    ),
    tabItems(
       tabItem("About", h1("text to be displayed"))
    )
)
```

but the "text to be displayed" shows up below the table.

What I want is, `About` section (when clicked) should display only the text and not the table. I understand this is just formatting of the code in `dashboardBody` section but I don't know how to do it.

Just to be more clear, my dashboard's section should display the datatable at all times and the `about` section when clicked should show up the text and not the datatable. I really hope this is clear. Thanks a ton for your help :)